# Deactivating or blocking the current order status

Tags: php, opencart-3

Is there any way for deactivating or blocking the current order status which is in use(admin end). I'm using opencart Version 3.0.3.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question, please explain exactly what you mean by blocking the current order status?

Comment: Is there any way for hiding the order status dropdown while installing a customised extension.

Comment: Why would you want to? While a user is installing an extension they will not be changing order statuses? Do you mean "while" or do you mean "after"?

Comment: im using customised status while installing

Answer (score 0):

You can find the select in the template and add a disabled attribute to it, then remove it after your installation is done.

In 3.0.3.1 the select is located in .../admin/view/template/sale/order_info.twig on line 224

`<select name="order_status_id" id="input-order-status" class="form-control">`

There might be other locations where it is possible to change the status of an order